# How can we automatically disable an Eclipse plug-in on target platforms?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We have developed an Eclipse plug-in called [CodingSpectator](http://codingspectator.cs.illinois.edu/) that collects some data about the usage of various Java development tools in Eclipse. This data helps us better understand how developers use Eclipse and how we can improve Eclipse to better suit the needs of programmers. CodingSpectator captures data from every workspace that is opened in Eclipse. Some of our users develop RCP applications or Eclipse plug-ins. Therefore, they run new instances of Eclipse from their main instance of Eclipse. However, we don't want CodingSpectator to collect data from the target platforms (new instances of Eclipse opened from within the main Eclipse). So, we instruct our users to configure their target platform to exclude CodingSpectator (See  http://codingspectator.cs.illinois.edu/resources/documentation/user-guide.html#htoc6). But, configuring the target platform manually is not convenient. And, we are looking for better ways to stop capturing data from target platforms.

How can we automatically disable CodingSpectator on the target platforms of our users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `Platform.inDevelopmentMode()` to determine if the instance Eclipse is run from within another instance of Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to look for the -dev application argument. This argument is always added by PDE when launching an application from within Eclipse.

Comment: How can I set the argument? How can I make sure that the argument is always set?

Comment: Hmm... maybe I misunderstood you. I though you just wanted to detect if you have been launched from within Eclipse. And for this you can use Platform.getApplicationArgs() and search for "-dev"..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Your suggestion seems promising. I'll give it a try.

Comment: `Platform.getApplicationArgs() ` returns an empty array when I run a new instance of Eclipse from within my instance of Eclipse.

Comment: Found it :-) Check out Platform.inDevelopmentMode()

Answer (score 0):

For at least RCP applications, it's likely that a target has already been defined, for stability across a team and a release.

But for those cases where someone wants to test a plug-in using the developer's version of Eclipse, perhaps you could provide a utility to make the target.

A target can be defined by a file in a project. You could provide a utility that generates the file. All the user would have to do would be:

1. Run your utility
2. Refresh the project (if necessary).
3. Open the generated target file in the Target Editor.
4. [OPTIONAL] Modify the generated target further.
5. Click on the "Set as Target Platform" link in the upper-left of the Target Editor.

Comment: We're looking for a fully automatic solution. Your answer is a step forward but doesn't fully resolve the issue.